# gdb (9.2) fails when trying to see variables content using Eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0) for C++, g++9, gdb9 under Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm sometimes unable to see variables content in Eclipse.

For standard type variables (boolean, int,...) it's OK, but for pointers it fails.

I get the following error:

```
Multiple error reported.
1) Connection is shut down
2) Unable to create variable object
```

It looks like that gdb fails because the debugged program stops !?

Here are some details:

- g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
- gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
- GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
- The gdp process line (using ps): `gdb --interpreter mi2 --nx -q --interpreter console -ex new-ui mi /dev/pts/1 -ex set pagination off -ex show version`

Any idea? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I was affected by this too, and spend time tracking down the issue to a gdb bug, which turns out to be known & fixed: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28711

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from gdb 9.2. Using gdb 8.3 whe have no more problem.